# How can I post req.body embedded mongo documents array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Is there a way to `POST /add` `req.body` this mongo model?

```
const QuestionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    description: String,
    alternatives: [{
            text: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            isCorrect: {
                type: Boolean,
                required: true,
                default: false
            }
        }
    ]
})
```

I got problems trying to post "alternatives" array subdocuments text and isCorrect.

hope your suggestions...

Comment: you probably need to provide more detail, on what you tried and some code examples.

Comment: yeah, please provide more detail with code examples of what you have tried and failed with ... you can certainly post data to mongoose, you just extract the data from `req.body`, assuming you sent your post request correctly

Answer (score 0):

More details...

Im using on my server.js

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}))
```

and my add post function:

```
router.post('/add', async (req, res) => {
    const {text} = req.body
    try {
        const question = new Question({
            "description": req.body.description, // save the question
        "alternatives": [{text},{"isCorrect": false}]}) //save de options answers alternatives

        await question.save();
        res.status(201).json(post);
}
     catch (error) {
        return res.status(500).json({"error":error})
    }
})
```

and wen a post from form, got this error:

```
{"error":{"errors":{"alternatives.0.text":{"stringValue":"\"[ 'Answer 1', 'Answer 2', 'Answer 3', 'Answer 4', 'Answer 5' ]\"","valueType":"Array","kind":"string","value":["Answer 1","Answer 2","Answer 3","Answer 4","Answer 5"],"path":"text","reason":null,"name":"CastError","message":"Cast to string failed for value \"[ 'Answer 1', 'Answer 2', 'Answer 3', 'Answer 4', 'Answer 5' ]\" (type Array) at path \"text\""},"alternatives.1.text":{"name":"ValidatorError","message":"Path `text` is required.","properties":{"message":"Path `text` is required.","type":"required","path":"text"},"kind":"required","path":"text"}},"_message":"Question validation failed","name":"ValidationError","message":"Question validation failed: alternatives.0.text: Cast to string failed for value \"[ 'Answer 1', 'Answer 2', 'Answer 3', 'Answer 4', 'Answer 5' ]\" (type Array) at path \"text\", alternatives.1.text: Path `text` is required."}}
```

Comment: I think it should be ```"alternatives": [{text, "isCorrect": false}]```

Comment: Cast to string failed for value \"[ 'Answer 1', 'Answer 2', 'Answer 3', 'Answer 4', 'Answer 5' ]\" (type Array) at path \"text\""}}

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what does your `req.body` actually contain but my guess is something like this:

```
{ "answers": ["Answer 1","Answer 2","Answer 3","Answer 4","Answer 5"] }
```

In that case, you want to map this array of strings to something that matches your schema:

```
const question = new Question({
      "description": req.body.description, // save the question
      "alternatives": req.body.answers.map(answer => ({
            text: answer,
            isCorrect: false // or true based on your logic
})
```